# How to load the value in angular using `rxJS`

Tags: angular, angular5

I require to load the values from google map. for that I trying like this:

```
public getCountry(lang,lat):Observable<any>{
        console.log( lang, lat );
        return this.http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false');
    }
```

But getting no result. how can i load the data from the above url?

any one help me?

**update**

```
if(navigator){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( pos => {

                this.latitude = pos.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = pos.coords.longitude;
                let data = this.server.getCountry(("latlng="+this.latitude+","), this.longitude);
                console.log('data', data );
            })
        }
```

Comment: Where do you call `getCountry` ?

Comment: I am calling from home page. the snippet is a service code from a service component

Comment: You are probably not subscribing correctly. It'd be useful to see the code where you call the function

Comment: @bugs see my update. present I am trying with hardcoded lat and lag, will update to dynamic

Comment: As I imagined, you are calling the function synchronously, so that when you try to print the value to the console it will still be undefined. Have a look at how to subscribe to observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

instead of

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false
```

because you fetching xml data not json

Comment: seems works, but no address component found. can you help me to subscribe the above result?

Comment: this.server.getCountry(("latlng="+this.latitude+","), this.longitude)
  .subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
  })

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answer, you might have to modify the way you call the API, but you also have to subscribe to your function in order to access the returned value.

```
this.server.getCountry(("latlng="+this.latitude+","), this.longitude)
  .subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
  })
```